# yolo9000 writing bounding box coordinates as .txt

Tags: output, bounding-box, darknet

I have been trying to write bounding box coordinates along with detected object name and the confidence value as a text file and output it as .txt file but in vain. I want something like following written as a .txt file:

[{"label":"person", "confidence": 0.56, "left": 184, "bottom": 101, "right": 274, "top": 382}]

I am relatively new in c programming language and yolo9000 is written in darknet in c. I am following the below implementation:

https://github.com/philipperemy/yolo-9000